# How can I determine if a Firestore snapshot is from the server?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My application stores in-memory copies of Firestore documents.   When data is changed by a given client, it first updates it's own in-memory copy, then writes those same updates to firebase.

```
function updateDoc(docPath, changes) {
  updateInMemoryDocWithChanges(changes);

  app.firebase.db.doc(docPath).update(updates);
}
```

It's possible these documents will be changed by other clients at the same time.   In order to capture these changes, we're using `onSnapshot({ includeMetadataChanges: true}, ...)` to listen for changes to those documents, only updates the in-memory copy when `hasPendingWrites` is `false`:

```
function handleSnapshot(doc) {
  // local write just occurred
  if (doc.metadata.hasPendingWrites) return;

  updateInMemoryObject(doc.data())
}
```

### The Problem

On slow connections, there can be a noticeable delay on receiving the `onSnapshot` event with `hasPendingWrites: false`.   So the following order of operations happens, but because of the delay, **the client is temporarily updated with stale data.**

1. `updateDoc()`
2. snapshot, `hasPendingWrites=true` (ignored)
3. another change is made, `updateDoc()` called again
4. snapshot,  `hasPendingWrites=false` from the update written in step 1. In memory copy is updated, *overwriting changes made in step 3!*
5. snapshot, `hasPendingWrites=true` with updates from step 3 (ignored)
6. then a few moments later..
7. snapshot, `hasPendingWrites=false` with updates from step 3. In memory copy is updated.

As a result the client sees some disconcerting loss of data before having it re-appear in 7.

I would like to simply ignore snapshot notifications that are the result of local client changes, but the only way I can see to do this is to match up snapshots that `hasPendingWrites=true` with `hasPendingWrites=false`, perhaps with the same doc?  Seems ugly and error prone.

What is the right way of approaching this?

Comment: Hey lambinator. Did you see my answer below? Did it make sense?

Comment: Thanks for the followup @FrankvanPuffelen -- see comment on your answer.

Comment: I realize now that what you're doing is uncommon: Firestore already fires local events when you perform a local write. So if you have a `onSnapshot` listener, you shouldn't have to call `updateInMemoryDocWithChanges` before sending it to the Firestore API, but instead should just call the Firestore API and then call `updateInMemoryDocWithChanges` in your `onSnapshot` listener. I think your current flow may actually be *causing* race conditions between multi-client updates, instead of protecting from them,

Comment: Isn't `onSnapshot` called from `firestore().update()` asynchronously?   There could be changes that happen between `updateDoc` and `onSnapshot` that would get overwritten if `updateInMemoryDocWIthChanges` was called from `onSnaphot` as you suggest?

Comment: The client-side event triggers right away, so there's no race condition there. If two clients are updating the same node, there is a potential they overwrite each other's changes, but that applies on the server already - not in your client code. Unless you use transactions, the last write will win. But I'm quite sure your code makes no difference to that, and actually introduces an additional race condition in the client.

Comment: It's not quite right away -- see this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geosteve/3L1kzv2a/58/).  Of course, this pseudocode is greatly simplified.   In practice, we actually debounce our updates (`updateInMemoryDocWithChanges`) to [throttle our writes to firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#updates_to_a_single_document), which is why we keep this in-memory copy separate from `onSnapshot` updates.  The in-memory copy reflects the current state of the UI.. which is why we want to know which updates are "external".

Answer (score 3):

To be sure the `DocumentSnapshot` corresponds to the current state of the database on the server, check [`docSnapshot.metadata.fromCache`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.SnapshotMetadata). If this property is `true`, the value is coming from the local cache and may not be up to date. If it is `false`, the value is guaranteed to be up to date with the server.

These properties go hand in hand for me, and I (currently) explain them to myself as:

- `hasPendingWrites` indicates if there are local changes to this document that haven't been sent to/handled by the server yet.
- `fromCache` indicates that this document may be stale. I think the property name is a bit unfortunate here, as its value indicates data freshness more than where the snapshot was loaded from.

Comment: Hey Puf!  Thanks for the quick answer.  Wanted to give it a try, and, unfortunately, it didn't help.  :( `fromCache` is almost always `false`, notably when `hasPendingUpdates=false` in step 4 of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in cases like this is to implement some form of data versioning. For example, add an integer `version` property that you increment each time you modify the object. Reject any updates with an older version than the in-memory copy. Your flow would become:

1. `updateDoc()` *(in-memory=1)*
2. snapshot, `hasPendingWrites=true` (ignored) *(snapshot=1)*
3. another change is made, `updateDoc()` called again  *(in-memory=2)*
4. snapshot,  `hasPendingWrites=false from the update written in step 1.  *(in-memory=2, shapshot=1)* **Update is rejected because memory version > snapshot version**
5. snapshot, hasPendingWrites=true with updates from step 3 (ignored)  *(snapshot=2)*
6. then a few moments later..
7. snapshot, hasPendingWrites=false with updates from step 3. *(in-memory=2, snapshot=2)* **In memory copy is updated because memory version <= snapshot version**