# In firestore, how to reliably determine if snapshot listener contains some changed data from the server?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

**Context:**

There have been a few posts about this topic already. Most notably this one: [How can I determine if a Firestore snapshot is from the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65851269/how-can-i-determine-if-a-firestore-snapshot-is-from-the-server).

Basically we have two variables that are passed from the snapshot listener, `fromCache` and `hasPendingWrites`. Here I am copying Frank's (in the above post) summary of them:

- `hasPendingWrites` indicates if there are local changes to this
  document that haven't been sent to/handled by the server yet.
- `fromCache` indicates that this document may be stale. I think the
  property name is a bit unfortunate here, as its value indicates data
  freshness more than where the snapshot was loaded from.

There is also an option to subscribe to metadata changes (this way, the snapshot listener will fire once when `hasPendingWrites` is true or `fromCache` is false, and then again when the listener knows it's up-to-date with the server)

**Problem**:

So I have a feature involving highlighting. These highlights are pushed to the server but are also listened to - for example, if you add/remove/change a highlight on one device, another one will listen to it and update it live.

When you change a highlight, that new data is pushed to the server via setDoc. This triggers the listener. If the change is local, we don't want the listener to update the local highlight store every time, because it's an expensive operation, and of course, because it's already updated. But obviously, we do want to update the store when new data has been pushed *from* the server.

Originally I was using `hasPendingWrites` [as described in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-local-changes). This was working fine, until I discovered a use case that it doesn't quite cover.

Let's say one device goes offline (`device A`), and makes some modifications to the highlights. These changes are cached locally. When the device comes back online, these changes are pushed to firestore. As expected, the listener triggers with `hasPendingWrites` set to true, and so we can safely assume that the changes have been local and there's no need to update the local store because it's already updated.

The issue is when `device B` has modified the highlights while `device A` was offline, *and* `device A` modified highlights locally while offline as well. When `device A` comes back online, the listener is only fired *once*. It seems that the changes that were made in `device B` as well as the changes are being pushed from `device A` are merged together. The problem is that this all condenses into *one listener trigger* with `hasPendingWrites` set to true because `device A` does indeed have some pending writes. Now `device A` thinks that the new snapshot contains *only local data* and so it doesn't update with `device B`'s new changes even though those changes are in the snapshot.

Here's a summary of the different scenarios from `device A`'s perspective:

- `device A` goes offline -> `device A` makes changes -> `device A` comes back online = one snapshot, `hasPendingWrites` set to true = do not update local store = all good
- `device A` goes offline -> `device *B*` makes changes -> `device A` comes back online = one snapshot, `hasPendingWrites` set to **false** = update local store = all good
- `device A` goes offline -> `device *B*` **and** `device *A*` makes changes -> `device A` comes back online = one snapshot, `hasPendingWrites` set to **true** = do not update local store = **undesirable**

`fromCache` doesn't seem to have much use here either way, as it's subject to a similar problem.

There is also a solution regarding [listening to metadata changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-metadata-changes), however this doesn't work either because if set to true, every time there is a local write, there is always then another listener triggered with `hasPendingWrites` set to false. This would re-build the local store with every write.

I thought of a workaround to listen to when the device comes back online, and set a flag for the next listener trigger to be an exception, but this is very dirty.

Comment: What would be really useful is: When listening for metadata changes, first of all a flag to determine whether or not the current snapshot is the second or first snapshot, and also a flag on the second snapshot that determines whether or not the data is different or the same as the data on the first.

Comment: Did the above way of listening to metadata changes solved your issue?

Comment: If you're referring to the above comment, that's not a solution I can implement. Those flags would have to be present in the snapshot object. The firestore devs would have to implement it.

Comment: "hasPendingWrites" is about writing the data to the backend, and shouldn't be used for transactional synchronization between multiple writers/readers.
As you noted, changes from different writers might be merged, and it's easy to imagine scenarios where multiple writers might have all made offline changes.
If you would like to avoid re-updating a writer's highlights, then the recommendation is a more robust approach of comparing the contents of the callback, instead of just looking at the high-level metadata.